# ¿Cómo mostrar el cursor de espera mientras se ejecuta una tarea intensiva?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un código JavaScript que realiza un procesamiento de datos bastante intensivo (tarda unos dos segundos en completarse) cuando el usuario pulsa un botón, y me gustaría establecer el cursor de espera a nivel global de la página mientras tanto.

Uso AngularJS y esto es lo que he intentado:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
$timeout(function() { document.body.style.cursor = 'wait'; }, 1)
    .then(function() { /*procesamiento intensivo aquí*/  })
    .then(function() { document.body.style.cursor = 'default'; });
```

...pero no funciona como esperaba: el procesamiento se realiza pero el cursor no cambia. Curiosamente, si elimino la última línea veo que el cursor sí cambia, pero *después* de finalizado el procesamiento.

Estoy seguro de que estoy pasando por alto algún aspecto esencial del ciclo de eventos del UI en Javascript, pero no consigo verlo. ¿Cómo podría conseguir que se vea el cursor de espera?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas.

El primero es que sólo cambias el cursor en el body (obviamente sobre el body sí se verá el cambio pero no en el resto de elementos), sugiero algo como

```
$("*").css("cursor", "progress")
....
$("*").css("cursor", "default")
```

El segundo es que realizas el cambio de cursor dentro del mismo ciclo de vista (Angular) por lo que el cambio de cursor no se realiza.

Este ejemplo funciona (asócialo a algún botón)

```
$timeout(function() {
  $("*").css("cursor", "progress");
  $timeout(function() {
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < 600000000; i++)
        x+=1/i;
    console.log(x);
  }, 20)
    .then(function() { $("*").css("cursor", "default") });
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta de josejuan ha funcionado con un pequeño cambio. He tenido que definir un estilo nuevo ([visto aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851881/4574)):

```
body.wait *, body.wait {
    cursor:wait !important;
}
```

...y el código queda:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $(document.body).addClass("wait");
  $timeout(function() {
    /* procesamiento */
  }, 50)
    .then(function() { $(document.body).removeClass("wait"); });
}, 50);
```

Nótese que también he tenido que aumentar el valor del intervalo para el timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Asocia el cursor a un elemento de tu $scope y actualiza el scope cuando entres en el procesamiento intensivo.

```
<div ng-if="processing">Work in progress...</div>
```

Y en tu javascript:

```
$scope.processing = true
```

Trata de evitar en la medida de lo posible mezclar javascript puro con angular, ya que vas a tener muchos problemas con los ciclos y la sincronización.

Comment: Buena alternativa, gracias, pero quería una solución simple que no implique hacer cambios en el HTML.